# How to check if there are Chartboost Rewarded Ads available to display?

Tags: ios, swift, chartboost

In my Swift iOS game I have a button that I show after the player loses, this button shows a rewarded ad from Chartboost.
The problem is that sometimes, i get an error on ad retrieval (error code 6) which is "No Ad Available". So i'm running out of ads for my region, i don't know why. Sometimes i'm able to watch 2-3 ads and that's all i can watch per day.
So when im running out of ads, the button still stays there of course, but does nothing. It might be confusing for the users to press the button and not see anything happening.
So i wanted to check if there are ads available, just hide the button.

The method i'm using to check if there is an ad available is:

```
Chartboost.hasRewardedVideo(CBLocationDefault)
```

But this somehow, is returning always **false**, no matter what CBLocation I use.

And I trigger the showAd() like this:

```
Chartboost.showRewardedVideo(CBLocationDefault)
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What region are you currently located in? Chartboost might have some trouble filling ad requests if you happen to be located in a country like Pakistan or Thailand. It may be a simple case of not having enough advertisers in your area that meet your publishing criteria.

Also, are you trying to show an ad right away on your application's bootup or is it ingame somewhere?

Comment: Im in Argentina yes. I allow the user to watch the ad when he loses... theres a button for the ad reward.

Comment: This almost certainly sounds like a fill rate issue then, given the fact that you can watch 2-3 ads before getting that error code.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to cut my response short.

Comment: Gah this mobile interface is crap. If you want to be absolutely sure, you can VPN in from a high fill location such as the US or the UK and if you can get repeated ads then the issue is 100% fillrate. This is really only an issue if the game is only released in Argentina and nowhere else, otherwise the players in high fill countries will get ads fine.

Comment: thanks amiry, what about checking if there are ads available? it returns always false :(